# How do I replace the release in sources.list?

Tags: apt, upgrade

Is there an easy way to replace all instances in /etc/apt/sources.list with the new release?

I want to replace all instances of my current release (whatever it is) with the new release for 14.04 "trusty"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just enter these commands on the console:

```
source /etc/lsb-release
NEW_RELEASE=trusty
sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.$DISTRIB_CODENAME 
sudo sed -i s/$DISTRIB_CODENAME/$NEW_RELEASE/g /etc/apt/sources.list
```

(It will also backup the current sources.list)